# Android App: My Manifest accepts all screen sizes but the Samsung GT-S6500D can't install it

Tags: android, eclipse, manifest, screen-size

I have an app in the Google Play Store.  I have set up the manifest so that for screen sizes it accepts small, medium, large, and extra large (all of the screen sizes).  The app is install-able on everything I've come across for both phones and tablets, EXCEPT now someone has mentioned that their Samsung mini 2 (Samsung GT-S6500D) doesn't let them install it. It tells them that the app is not compatible with their device.

I've already verified they are running Android 2.3.6, and my app works for anyone with 2.3.3 or below.

I've also been told the Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 says it is not compatible.  Why is this happening??

Is there something I am missing to allow for all phones / tablets to use my app?

This is my Manifest:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="xxx"
      android:versionCode="xx"
      android:versionName="xx">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    <supports-screens 
                      android:smallScreens="true"
                      android:normalScreens="true"
                      android:largeScreens="true"
                      android:xlargeScreens="true"
                      />
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:allowBackup="true">
        <activity android:name=".ItineraryHomeActivity"
                     android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  >
                  <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />   
                </intent-filter>
                <intent-filter>
                  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                  <data android:scheme="file" />
                  <data android:host="*" />
                  <data android:port="*" />
                  <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
                  <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.tgtp" />
                </intent-filter>
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                    <data android:mimeType="text/xml" />
                 </intent-filter>

        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".EditHomeItListActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" android:label="@string/itinerary_title"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnchanged"
         />

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Shouldn't this make the app available to every single android device running 2.3.3 an above?

Comment: You should probably post your entire AndroidManifest. It could be something else.

Comment: I've gotten the "This app is not compatible with your device" on a tablet of mine that had a glitched Google Play app, through no fault of the 3rd party app. Is it sure that this device is working properly? In my case, a factory reset had to be done.

Comment: Does that "glitched" tablet not allow you to install any apps, or just one in particular?

Comment: It would allow most, but I'd say about 1/10 of apps it simply wouldn't install. They didn't seem to have anything in common, and it was consistent in which ones it would reject.

Comment: Hmm ok, do you happen to have one app in general that it didn't install so I could try it?  I want to see if I replicate it.

Comment: It's been a couple months, but I think one was Pixel Dungeon. Could be wrong, though. Since you added the bit with the Galaxy Tab 2, I'm less confident this is your problem. I don't see anything wrong with your manifest, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  The line that says you need camera permission was being used as a filter in the google play store:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

I don't know why this was the case because all of the phones / tablets that didn't work already had a camera...  but the fix was to change it to the "uses-feature" tag instead and not make it required:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

Hope this helps someone

Comment: did you mean <uses-feature
  android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />